# Wordpress twentyseventeen - where does the css class has-sidebar come from?

Tags: css, wordpress

so I'm trying to modifiy wordpress twentyseventeen theme.
As you can see the div is using primary id and content-area class.

However in chrome expector it's using has-sidebar class instead.
Can anyone please explain how the hell where this has-sidebar is coming from?
Couldn't find any link...
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `.has-sidebar` is automatically added to the `body` tag of all pages which have a sidebar (by Wordpress).

In combination with other classes (in rules with combined CSS selectors as the one in your example) this makes it possible to make the layout of particular elements depend on whether the page has a sidebar. (i.e. whether a particular rule is applied or not)

Answer (score 0):

`.has-sidebar` is your `body` class. The css rule `.has-sidebar:not(.error404) #primary` say: in `.has-sidebar`, which not contain `.error404` class add some rule to element with id `#primary`.

Its giving more ways for styling your html pages. That classes added to body with `js/php` scripts to make difference between simple page, page with sidebar, page without sidebar, page with fixed menu and etc.

Comment: I have some created a custom template for custom post types, without a sidebar.
Where can I remove this class from my body?
Instead I want to add another class called no-sidebar.

Comment: you don't need to remove class and add another. you called sidebar in your custom template. provide template code. then I can be helpful